# identityserver4 oid additional scope not appear request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

i'm currently following this tutorial on identityserver doc:

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html

I want to add additional identity scope(email) to the consent page, the question is why the scope in the client OpenIdConnectOptions is readonly ?

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";                    
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.Resource = "openid profile email";      
                **options.Scope= // why this readonly ?**
                options.ClientId = "mvc";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });
```

This resulting the requested scope only profile and openid.
http://localhost:5000/account/login?returnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3Dmvc%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A5002%252Fsignin-oidc%26resource%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520email%26response_type%3Did_token%26**scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%26**rest are omited

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IdentityServer4 v2 the Scope parameter is a collection. Add a scope like this:

```
options.Scope.Add("myscope");
```

Comment: OMG you're right...very simple but i get confused with read only -.-